# Visual studio publish profiles and its configurations

Tags: visual-studio, publish, buildconfiguration, publish-profiles

I'm trying to get a better understanding of visual studios build configurations.

I'm currently building out a webAPI. 
I am also using team city for some automated build tasks and so I use a different profile for that instead of the debug profile that I use locally. This team city profile also has its own configuration (I'm using it for transforms). Because I use this configuration, I am unable to attach to it (it has error I can't reproduce locally).

Is there a way to use a custom configuration while building out all the symbols and debug data that the debug configuration has so I can still attach. I've tried finding more information by searching but I can't seem to find the right info I'm looking for. Perhaps a cleaner explanation of profiles and configurations would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you want to enable debugging symbols in a build configuration other than `Debug`.

To achieve that, right click on your project, open its **Properties**, and switch to the **Build** tab:

[image]
There you can tick the checkbox to `Define DEBUG constant` and untick `Optimize code` which should enable you to properly debug your build even when using a build configuration that's not `Debug`.